# How to login webpage that requires QR code scanning with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, barcode

I want to login a web-page to get data with PyQt5.

However, the web-page requires me to scan an QR-code with my mobile.

I have no idea on how to work it out.

I search on the web and found that `zxing` project can decode barcode.

The webiste is `https://login.tmall.com`

Then, follow the images below to get the QR code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: Could you explain your more precise objective, pointing to "login to web-page" is very generic. From what the qrcode analyzes it only generates a url: `https://login.m.taobao.com/mlogin/login.htm`, and then the logic of the authentication is handled by your cell phone.

Comment: Can PyQt5 show the QR code for me to scan using mobile phone?

Comment: Do you want PyQt5 to emulate the click in the upper left part so that the qrcode is shown?

Comment: Yes. After I authenticate using mobile, can PyQt5 get the html data as usual?

Comment: What do you want the HTML for?

Comment: I mean getting the product information in the online store after login.

Comment: From what I understand you want the page to be shown with the qrcode, then you scan it with your cell phone so it will be logged in, and then you want the HTML of the page that is loaded after login, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Can I do it or it is impossible?